# neo4j and Mongodb together lin

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, cypher, multiple-databases, querying

I'm trying to implement this notion of multiple databases.
I made a simple graph of a community and I had stored the informations of each node as a document in Mongodb.
Now I'm working on the query part, I dont find it clear when I return a subgraph and I need to return all of the informations of each node from Mongodb . I can't seem to get the way of liking the result on neo4j with the next query on Mongodb for extracting more details

Should I make another query to find each node in mongodb , yet it will not be useful for a large set .
I have already checked https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager ,  but my needs aren't synchronization ... I just want to get the details of the result nodes from neo4j 
Any clarifications will be appreciated

Comment: Check out https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j_doc_manager for some hints

Comment: @TomažBratanič Actually I did see the doc you mentionned, It converts the node to document so that the systems is synchronized and consistent . yet what I'm interested in is just the extraction of informations for example a result of a query returns  node of Id=3  I need to get more informations of that node from mongodb

Comment: If you need to get data from a mongodb DB, you have to make mongodb queries. If you want to avoid that, then all your data should be in your neo4j DB.

Comment: @cybersam look, the problem is how to iterate over the result of the query from neo4j and get more details from mongodb documents . of course in mongo there should be mongodb queries

Comment: You may want to take a look at [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) as it has support for [making calls to other dbs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_loading_data_from_rdbms) from within a Cypher query. There is support for Mongo db in there

Comment: @InverseFalcon , I will definitely check it out thank you